# Compare current pixel value with the previous one on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

Is possible to implement this image filtering process in numpy array ? I need to check if the pixel in the previous column and previous row is differente of the current pixel.

```
width, height = orig_bin.size
pixels = orig_bin.load()

delta = 50
begin = 10
min_w = 30
max_w = 260
min_h = 10
max_h = 40

w_range = range(begin, width - min_w - delta)
h_range = range(begin, height - min_h - delta)

is_changing = False
for x in w_range:
    for y in h_range:
        change_pixel = False
        current_pixel = pixels[x,y]
        if current_pixel != pixels[x, y+1]:
            change_pixel = True

        if current_pixel != pixels[x+1, y]:
            change_pixel = True

        if change_pixel:
            pixels[x,y] = (0,0,0)
        else:
            pixels[x,y] = (255,255,255)
```

Best regards,
Emilio

Comment: Is there a problem with this implementation or are you looking to optimize?  What's the question here specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach. Take an [example image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Utah_teapot_simple_2.png):

[image: Render of Utah teapot model by Martin Newell]

You didn't say where your `orig_bin` came from, so I've used [`scipy.misc.imread`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html):

```
from scipy.misc import imread, imsave
img = imread('input.png')
```

First, create a mask for pixels that are different from the pixel above (this uses an idea from [Bi Rico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22079952/68063)):

```
up   = (img[1:,1:] != img[:-1,1:]).any(axis=2)
```

Note that `imread` loads images in row-major order, so the first NumPy axis is the vertical axis. See "[Multidimensional Array Indexing Order Issues](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues)" for an explanation.

Similarly, create a mask for pixels that are different from the pixel to the left:

```
left = (img[1:,1:] != img[1:,:-1]).any(axis=2)
```

Combine these to get a mask for pixels that are different to either the pixel above or left:

```
mask = numpy.zeros(img.shape[:2], dtype=bool)
mask[1:,1:] = left | up
```

Create a black output image of the right size; then set the mask to white:

```
output = numpy.zeros(img.shape)
output[mask] = (255, 255, 255)
imsave('output.png', output)
```

And here's the result:

[image: Output white]

or if you want the colours to be the other way round, invert the mask:

```
output[~mask] = (255, 255, 255)
```

[image: Output black]

Comment: Good spot! Fixed; and I adopted your idea of computing a smaller mask.

Comment: Gareth Rees, Is possible to invert the colors ? The mask use (0,0,0) and the color is filled with 255,255,255 ?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
change = (pixels[1:, 1:] != pixels[1:, :-1]) | (pixels[1:, 1:] != pixels[:-1, 1:])
```

This will be binary (True, False), you'll need to multiply it by 255 if you want your result to be 0/255. You also might need to run and any on the last dimension if you array is (x, y, 3).

There are other ways you could re-cast this problem, for example a convolution with [1, -1] might get you most of the way there.

Comment: I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together` when I try this.

Comment: @GarethRees, the left and right side of `|` should have the same shape. I've fixed the issue.